# Why do I earn so little xp?

Tags: world-of-warships

I'm playing World of Warships (on Xbox, against other people, not bots), and I do pretty decent, 3 destroyed 80k damage (tier 5). The battle ends with a victory and I GET LIKE 80 XP!

I need around 25k more, so at that rate, before I can get my next ship, it would take a lot of games. Assuming each game lasts around 10 minutes, 1 hour wouldn't even get me 1M xp. I don't plan on spending over 30 hours for an online boat.

I googled for information on this, and most results were related to calculating the xp, not why one would get so little. The worst part is that in one of my first battles I did terribly, and got over 25k xp.

So my question is: why am I getting such a small amount of xp?
How can I increase the experience I gain?

Comment: If possible, can you post some of your end-game results ? (with the EXP, and the details of how you did in the battle)